# React & TypeScript: How do i override these two functions in order to clear an error dialogue after GET request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, typescript, error-handling

#### Problem

I am making an Ajax `GET` request which populates a drop down list based on the input given. For some reason, my `onChange()` is not working as expected. I assumed that when the user typed a new value with focus changed, the request would trigger. Instead every time i type the request is being triggered. Its behaving like `onkeypress()` even though its `onChange()`. Now this is not a problem, the problem is if the value is invalid, an error will be returned. Lets say i want to type 205 and as soon as i type 2 it will send that request thus resulting in an error dialogue. I have debugged and the program generates an error on the following two functions coming from the file `StackTraceViewer.ts`.

#### Error Functions

```
    function ajaxError(xhr: JQueryXHR) {
            if (xhr.hasOwnProperty("responseJSON")) {
                responseJsonError(xhr.responseJSON);
            }
            else if (xhr.hasOwnProperty("responseText")) {
                responseTextError(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }

function responseJsonError(json: any) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty("Message")) {
            Cama.error(json.hasOwnProperty("ExceptionMessage") ? json.ExceptionMessage : json.Message);
            addAjaxStackTrace(json);
        }
        else {
            Cama.error("An unknown ajax error has occurred");
        }
    }
```

The error returned is:The request in invalid. How do i override these functions? I tried defining the error like `error: function(err)` to my request but it did not work. I also tried to check if the request is 400 so i would call `Cal.clearErrors()`(function that clears errors) however, that did not work either.